# update cmake in clion in windows

Tags: c++, cmake, clion

I got a error in clion:
CMake 3.15 or higher is required.  You are running version 3.14.5

then I installed the newest version cmake and cmake installer from cmake.org

[I downloaded this two links](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EGm1x.png)

then I added the installed path of "cmake-3.17.2-win64-x64" in my environment variables.

now I have version cmake 3.17.2 when I check in cmd

[image]

now how can I update my cmake version in my clion2019?

Answer (score 0):

Answering your question, you can change CMake executable path in *Preferences | Build, Execution, Deployment | Toolchains*

[image]

> I got a error in clion: CMake 3.15 or higher is required. You are
>   running version 3.14.5

Are you sure that your project need CMake 3.15? It much easier to change `cmake_minimum_required` in your CMakeLists.txt and use Bundled CMake 3.14.5.